# Can I hide parts of the store with Zustand?

Tags: reactjs, zustand

I have an authentication store implemented with Zustand in a React app. One of the actions implemented in the store (*primary*) needs to **check a variable and based on that value call one of two possible other actions** (*secondary*).

All of these three actions need to access the Zustand state, either for getting or setting parts of the state, but **I'd like for the secondary actions not to be accessible by the React components**.

I can extract the secondary actions from the store and pass them the getters and setters as parameters, but I'd like to know: **is there a built-in way for Zustand to hide part of the state when accessing it**?